# Can an Azure Function using an EventGrid binding trigger return a 202 before then continuing async?

Tags: php, azure, azure-functions, serverless

Using Azure Functions can I return an accepted http 202 response to the caller (if the request is valid), before then running a longer function asynchronously, without needing to use a durable function in the middle?

The use case for this is for a custom handler function [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-custom-handlers).

I want to run a PHP job which may take longer than 30 seconds (as much as 3-4 minutes).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using durable functions, you could have a simple function that takes the event data and queues a message for another function to pick up and process.

You could even configure Event Grid to [send the event to a queue directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/handler-service-bus) as well.

**UPDATE:** Another option is to package the PHP script in a container and run it using [Azure Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/container-instances/container-instances-overview). You could even leverage [Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview) and the [Azure Container Instance Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/aci/) to start the container, all without writing any code.

Comment: The problem with this is that a service bus queue input binding then requires the function to continuously poll the queue. We just moved off of service bus both as its very expensive and our use case has few events (may go days without an event, so is more efficient to be triggered by one).

Comment: Updated my answer with an alternate. Hope that helps.